# Put up at vs. put up in

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, phrasal-verbs

Consider the following examples:

> 1. We put up **at** a hotel in the city centre.
> 2. We put up **in** a hotel in the city centre.

To me, the first example sounds better than the second one. Can we use the preposition “in” after the phrasal verb “put up” here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either preposition. Neither is more 'natural' or 'better'.

> Put up
>   verb 6a
>   INTRANSITIVE ​OLD-FASHIONED
>   to stay for a short
>   time in a place that is not your home
>   put up at/in:
>   We put up at a
>   cheap hotel.

[Put up (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/put-up)